# Where does the software-center store its history?

Tags: apt, software-center, history, installed-programs

The Ubuntu software center is able to display a detailed history of packages installed /updated/removed according to date.

1. Where does it get this info from? (`/var/log/dpkg.log` is maintained only for 12 months; I don't know of any apt-* or dpkg commands to get the date when a package was first installed.)
2. How can I **copy** this data in the form of a table / text to be processed by another program?

Comment: You could try looking through `/var/log/apt/history.log` or the archived .gzs in the same folder, but I doubt it would go back 12 months back too. A year is a long time to keep logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought the specifics are fairly useless, Unless you want to find out exactly what changes were made to the system on a specific day and time, I felt the steps I went through to discover this information were worth documenting:

I ran `strace -e trace=open -f -o usc software-center` to get a list of all the files opened by the software center. Then I filtered it like this.

```
cat usc| grep -oP '(?<=open\(").*(?=",)' |egrep -v '\.(so\.([0-9]|cache)|so|pyc|mo|py|png|svg)$'|egrep -v '/usr/lib/(python2.7|x86|girepo)'| egrep -v '/usr/share/(icons|themes)' |egrep -v '/etc/fonts'|egrep -v '(screenshots|reviews)\.ubuntu\.com' |egrep -v fontconfig |sort -u
```

to eliminate all the files didn't contain data files.

Among these I found the interesting looking looking file: `~/.cache/software-center/apthistory.p` It looked like a python pickle file when I opened it. trying to load the file I got the error that `softwarecenter.db.history_impl.apthistory` was not imported.  I ran the following command to look for python files that ere opened and had  "softwarecenter" in their path

```
$cat usc| grep -oP '(?<=open\(").*(?=",)' |grep softwarecenter
```

and got a whole bunch of filenames including `/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/history_impl/apthistory.so` I wrote the following script to read and process file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import pickle

sys.path.append('/usr/share/software-center')
import softwarecenter.db.history_impl.apthistory

with open(os.path.expanduser('~/.cache/software-center/apthistory.p')) as IFile:
    hist=pickle.load(IFile)

print type(hist[0])
print "earliest apt transaction started on:",hist[-1].start_date
print "installed:"
for PackageStr in hist[-1].install:
    print PackageStr
print "upgraded:"
for PackageStr in hist[-1].upgrade:
    print PackageStr
```

I found the necessary attributes by looking up the class of which hist[0] was an instance of: `help(softwarecenter.db.history_impl.apthistory.AptTransaction)`. This lead me to the parent class `help( softwarecenter.db.history.Transaction)` from where I figured out how to use it.

Btw even `sudo apt-get install`ed stuff appears here.

Answer (score 2):

All history of packages installed/updated/removed is in `/var/log/apt`: new history in `history.log` file, old history in archives, in `history.log.x.gz` files. See the image below to get this data in a form of a table in Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: USC - history]

Comment: the data in this table cannot be copied/exported :/. In `/var/log/apt/history.log` the logs go back only 12 months. However the USC shows records from well before that.

Comment: @staticd I don't see any good/useful reason to copy/export this history. All  history is in `/var/log/apt`: new history in `history.log`, old history in archives, in `history.log.x.gz` files.

Comment: old archives go back only 12 months.

Comment: @staticd I just opened `history.log.5.gz/history.log.5` file and the first line from there is: `Start-Date: 2012-10-17  14:57:48`. So, you have no right.